# Query SQL display score

Tags: mysql

I need some help. I want to display All scores from students, If the score has been input to db, it will display the score, if not it will display null value.

Database structure like this :

**students**

- nim
- name
- class_year (like : 2020, 2021, etc)

**krs**

- code_krs
- nim
- academic_year (like : 20201, 20202, etc)
- total_sks

**krs_detail**

- id
- code_krs
- course_code
- sks

**courses**

- course_code
- course_name
- sks

**scores**

- academic_year (like : 20201, 20202, etc)
- course_code
- nim
- score

I try query like this :
`

```
SELECT students.nim, students.name, krs_detail.course_code, courses.course_name, courses.sks, scores.score
FROM students
JOIN scores ON scores.nim = students.nim
RIGHT JOIN courses ON courses.course_code = scores.course
JOIN krs_detail ON krs_detail.course_code = courses.course_code
WHERE krs_detail.code_krs = '1411503293-20222';
```

Data displayed is correct, with nim & name student :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rvaky.png)

But, if i change **krs_detail.code_krs** with other data, example **2161206003-20211**, data displayed is wrong :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNEpR.png)

All data **score** should be null/empty, because score has not been insert to db, nim displayed : 2161206003, name : Farhan.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My interpretation is that

- There are two master tables: `students` and `courses`.
- A student can take a number of courses in an academic year, which is recorded in `krs` and `krs_detail`
- A student will receive a score for the course he takes in the academic year, which is recorded in `scores` table.

If so, the data model looks like below:

[image: Data Model Diagram]

The score report needs to display

- All the courses taken by a student, and
- All the scores received by a student
- If a score is not yet available, display the `course code`, `course name` and `sks`.

If the above is correct, the granularity of the dataset is (`nim`, `academic_year`, `course_code`)

We can

- First, generate the result of all the courses taken by students
- Second, left outer join from the above to `scores` to retrieve `score`.

```sql
select s.nim,
       s.name,
       k.academic_year,
       d.course_code,
       c.course_name,
       c.sks,
       sc.score
  from students s
  join krs k
    on s.nim = k.nim
  join krs_detail d
    on k.code_krs = d.code_krs
  join courses c
    on d.course_code = c.course_code
  left
  join scores sc
    on s.nim = sc.nim
   and k.academic_year = sc.academic_year
   and d.course_code = sc.course_code
 order by s.nim, d.course_code;
```

An example of result:

```
nim|name|academic_year|course_code|course_name                |sks|score|
---+----+-------------+-----------+---------------------------+---+-----+
101|adam|         2022|        401|An Introduction to Computer|  3|   85|
101|adam|         2022|        402|Programming Language       |  3|     |
201|eve |         2022|        401|An Introduction to Computer|  3|   90|
201|eve |         2022|        402|Programming Language       |  3|     |
```